# R in Jupyter Notebook returns following error: `ERROR while rich displaying an object:`

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

Does anyone have a solution to following problem in Jupyter with R?
This error message does not appear with Python or Julia and is printed when I do not print an object.

works without error: `print(x)`

works with error: `x`

```
ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error in withCallingHandlers({: No repr_* for mimetype application/geo+json in repr::mime2repr

Traceback:
1. FUN(X[[i]], ...)
2. tryCatch(withCallingHandlers({
 .     if (!mime %in% names(repr::mime2repr)) 
 .         stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
 .     rpr <- repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
 .     if (is.null(rpr)) 
 .         return(NULL)
 .     prepare_content(is.raw(rpr), rpr)
 . }, error = error_handler), error = outer_handler)
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
6. withCallingHandlers({
 .     if (!mime %in% names(repr::mime2repr)) 
 .         stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
 .     rpr <- repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
 .     if (is.null(rpr)) 
 .         return(NULL)
 .     prepare_content(is.raw(rpr), rpr)
 . }, error = error_handler)
7. stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error in withCallingHandlers({: No repr_* for mimetype application/vdom.v1+json in repr::mime2repr

Traceback:
1. FUN(X[[i]], ...)
2. tryCatch(withCallingHandlers({
 .     if (!mime %in% names(repr::mime2repr)) 
 .         stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
 .     rpr <- repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
 .     if (is.null(rpr)) 
 .         return(NULL)
 .     prepare_content(is.raw(rpr), rpr)
 . }, error = error_handler), error = outer_handler)
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
6. withCallingHandlers({
 .     if (!mime %in% names(repr::mime2repr)) 
 .         stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
 .     rpr <- repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
 .     if (is.null(rpr)) 
 .         return(NULL)
 .     prepare_content(is.raw(rpr), rpr)
 . }, error = error_handler)
7. stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error in withCallingHandlers({: No repr_* for mimetype application/vnd.plotly.v1+json in repr::mime2repr

Traceback:
1. FUN(X[[i]], ...)
2. tryCatch(withCallingHandlers({
 .     if (!mime %in% names(repr::mime2repr)) 
 .         stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
 .     rpr <- repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
 .     if (is.null(rpr)) 
 .         return(NULL)
 .     prepare_content(is.raw(rpr), rpr)
 . }, error = error_handler), error = outer_handler)
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
6. withCallingHandlers({
 .     if (!mime %in% names(repr::mime2repr)) 
 .         stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
 .     rpr <- repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
 .     if (is.null(rpr)) 
 .         return(NULL)
 .     prepare_content(is.raw(rpr), rpr)
 . }, error = error_handler)
7. stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error in withCallingHandlers({: No repr_* for mimetype application/vnd.vegalite.v2+json in repr::mime2repr

Traceback:
1. FUN(X[[i]], ...)
2. tryCatch(withCallingHandlers({
 .     if (!mime %in% names(repr::mime2repr)) 
 .         stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
 .     rpr <- repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
 .     if (is.null(rpr)) 
 .         return(NULL)
 .     prepare_content(is.raw(rpr), rpr)
 . }, error = error_handler), error = outer_handler)
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
6. withCallingHandlers({
 .     if (!mime %in% names(repr::mime2repr)) 
 .         stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
 .     rpr <- repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
 .     if (is.null(rpr)) 
 .         return(NULL)
 .     prepare_content(is.raw(rpr), rpr)
 . }, error = error_handler)
7. stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error in withCallingHandlers({: No repr_* for mimetype application/vnd.vega.v4+json in repr::mime2repr

Traceback:
1. FUN(X[[i]], ...)
2. tryCatch(withCallingHandlers({
 .     if (!mime %in% names(repr::mime2repr)) 
 .         stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
 .     rpr <- repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
 .     if (is.null(rpr)) 
 .         return(NULL)
 .     prepare_content(is.raw(rpr), rpr)
 . }, error = error_handler), error = outer_handler)
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
6. withCallingHandlers({
 .     if (!mime %in% names(repr::mime2repr)) 
 .         stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
 .     rpr <- repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
 .     if (is.null(rpr)) 
 .         return(NULL)
 .     prepare_content(is.raw(rpr), rpr)
 . }, error = error_handler)
7. stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
```

Comment: this might be a duplicate of [link](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/590) on that site there was a [link2](https://github.com/IRkernel/repr/issues/100) where someone (flying-sheep) suggested to install the latest version of repr `devtools::install_github('IRkernel/repr')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not find the underlying problem, but updating the repr as suggested by flying-sheep on [github](https://github.com/IRkernel/repr/issues/100) solved my problem.

`devtools::install_github('IRkernel/repr')`

repr is a "string and byte representations for all kinds of R objects." More information can be found on [github](https://github.com/IRkernel/repr)